# Regex table is causing this error - LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use a table made of two columns(regex and channel) to create a custom channel grouping column in several other tables.

We have several tables in our organization with google analytics data and we manually create regular expressions in every query to create custom channel grouping (Paid Media , Organic , Direct etc...) using my source_medium column. I want to centralize this, creating a table of two columns (regex , channel) and use as a subquery in our queries to create a new column called channel.

The custom_channel_table has the following structure(example):

```
[           REGEX               ,   CHANNEL  ]
[  "^(\(direct\) \/ \(none\)) " ,  "direct"  ]
[  "(organic)"                  ,  "organic" ]
[  "^(google \/ cpc) "          ,  "google"  ]
```

and the main_table has the following structure:

```
 [   SOURCE_MEDIUM   ]
 ["(direct) / (none)"]
 [   "google / cpc"  ]
 [   "organic"       ]
```

WHen I run the query I expect the result:

```
 [   SOURCE_MEDIUM   , CHANNEL  ]
 ["(direct) / (none)", "direct" ]
 [   "google / cpc"  , "google" ]
 [   "organic"       , "organic"]
```

but I get the following code error.

> LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.

This is my query:

```
SELECT source_medium ,
       ( SELECT channel
         FROM custom_channel_table
         WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(source_medium, regex) = source_medium) AS channel 
FROM  main_table;
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: This seems to return rows (outer query) where one field is rows (inner query) from a subselect. Are you sure the inner query will always, only, every time, return 1 row, and 1 row only?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen , I'm sure it will return only 1 row every time.

Comment: @GordonLinoff , I edited my question, I think it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You can attempt this with a `CROSS JOIN` and then `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT source_medium ,
       ( SELECT channel
         FROM custom_channel_table
         WHERE REGEXP_EXTRACT(source_medium, regex) = source_medium) AS channel 
FROM main_table;
```

Note:  You are using `REGEXP_EXTRACT()`.  I would recommend using `REGEXP_CONTAINS()` instead.  However, that is not relevant to your question.